# nginx cannot proxy errors from node.js app

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a `node.js` app and `nginx` server. Have a problem when uploading files without authorization. App throws 401 error, but `nginx` sometimes has `writev() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream` error and response is 502. I suppose that it depends on buffering, but I don't know how.

If i try GET requests without auth, everything works fine, status code is 401.

Node app is in docker container, but I think it doesn't matter.

My `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}

events {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by turning off request buffering.
`proxy_request_buffering off;`

Also I added `client_body_buffer_size 20M;` for performance.